# Keyboard macro get data from one buffer and put to another buffer

Tags: keyboard-macros

I use keyboard macros in one buffer like this:

```
'C-x (’ or <f3>– start defining a keyboard macro
`C-x )’ or <f4>– stop defining the keyboard macro
```

Nice. It's work fine.
But I use macro in on buffer. 
But suppose I has 2 buffers. I split window. In the top I has `countries.xml` and in bottom buffer I has `insert-data.sql`

Is it possible to create keyboard macro that copy data, line by line, from `insert-data.sql` and paste to `countries.xml` ?

Here screenshot:

[image: keyboard-macro]

I know that I can write elisp script. But I want to do this task by keyboard macros. Is it possible?

Comment: You can simply switch windows or buffers in your macro, but you have to make sure your macro ends up with a reasonable state so it can be repeated.

Comment: [@DoMiNeLa10]: I think you answered well.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, you can include buffer-switching in your macro as long as you're consistent about where you start/end.

Another approach might be to use commands in your macro that keep you in one buffer but allow you to push text to the other one, such as `append-to-buffer` or `prepend-to-buffer`.